# Dystopia vs Utopia - Possible to coincide?

Tags: dystopia, utopia

**Utopia within a Dystopian world?**

Or would this be a Utopia slowly diminishing into the state of being a Dystopia?......Hmmm

**Question**

Within a futuristic world overrun by another "intelligent" species...

- Is it possible to turn the world from a Utopia to a Dystopia while still 
  keeping a "Headquarters" that is utopian?

I want my world to have a center where the "wealthy" are in a utopian environment while the rest are in a distopian environment.

**Thoughts**

Maybe it would be more logical/pleasing to have an Oasis within a Dystopian world rather than trying to create a utopian place within a dystopian world?

What I am asking for are opinions/logic. Does this idea seem feasible or just complete non-sense.

If this is too vague, I apologize in advance. I haven't created my world, only the species and creatures that would inhabit it.

Comment: Hi. Please, one question per question.

Comment: @Mołot Will do, I thought it might be bad to post multiple questions regarding the same subject by the same poster. I will consider this going forward. :)

Comment: Posting multiple questions is no problem. The best approach is to ask one specific answerable question per post, then wait a bit for answers to come in and maybe a day or so later post the next question, referring to the first one with a link, incoporating the answers into the new one, restating the premise and explicitly showing what the new, different question is about.

Comment: @Secespitus Thank you for the guidance! I will do this going forward. :)

Comment: The answer would be: Yes because what is Utopia is defined from within and not from outside standards. What is dystopia to one can be utopia for others. Example: people living in USA are feeling they live in dystopia while other come to the same country to live in utopia.

Comment: As I understand your question it is more a case of philosophy - philosophical questions by definition do not have a clear answer.

Comment: Now you have 3 bullets. What if one person answers first bullet and another person second bullet? What if answers to one bullet are in conflict with answers to another one? As @Secespitus said, chains of questions are OK, encouraged even.

Comment: @molot I completely understand. I'm sorry.

Comment: No problem. You can edit your current question if it wouldn't invalidate already-posted answers. If it already would, then limit your editing to pointing out which part is most important for now, and just keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: There is a button at the end of your post that says "edit" and allows you to [edit] your post. Be careful to not invalidate existing answers if you can help it. (We are weird and some rules seem contradictory at first. You get used to it eventually. I hope you stick around.) And have a look at the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) on meta in case you want feedback on whether soemthing would be on-topic first. Just a tip, you don't need to use the Sandbox in case you don't want to.

Comment: @secespitus will do! I am liking it a lot so far and imagine I'll be around for a while longer. :) I will get right on editing once I get back on my computer in about 15 min or so. :)

Comment: @secespitus it seems it is on hold now for being too broad. :/

Comment: @KourtneySmith Yes, if five members vote to put a question temporarily on hold this happens to make sure that a question can be edited before any (/too many) answers roll in. Editing too much might invalidate them, which is bad practice, but the author needs to adhere to the guidelines. **I think this question is fine after your edits and will nominate it for reopening.** An edit from you (or me starting the process) will send this question to a reopen review queue where it takes a total of five other members with at least 3k rep to reopen the question. This may take a while though.

Comment: @secespitus Thanks for the help! I'll get the hang of this eventually! :)

Comment: Your question is the premise of the movie *[Elysium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elysium_(film))*.

Comment: @JBH ... and half of all other dystopian/utopian stories as well, no? However, I will admit that Elysium was among the first to come to mind. There's also Equilibrium (though we saw only 1 person living their utopia), Altered Carbon, Snowpiercer, The Island (though here the divide is not wealth or arbitrary caste)... while reading this question, my thought was "What story does _not_ fit this description?"

Answer (score 6):

A utopia relies on sufficient resources for all. A dystopia happens when there is a shortage of resources

You can have a utopia inside a dystopia where there isn't enough resources for all but what resources there is is channeled to a group leaving the rest with less.

If you look at [The Hunger Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hunger_Games_(film)), the Capital is a utopia with advanced technology, medicine, entertainment, fashion and the citizens live a life of luxury but the Districts are kept poor and repressed because the resources they produce are channeled to the Capital.

Comment: This is golden. Great example and the explanations helped me gain a clearer perspective on the differences between the two and how they would work in unison. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to turn the world from a Utopia to a Dystopia while still keeping a "Headquarters" that is utopian?

Absolutely.  There's countless ways to make this work.  One extreme example is with neural interconnects or drugs which let someone live in a Utopian world while the actual world crumbles beneath them.  This is actually quite a common trope with VR

> Would the Utopian world slowly diminish and eventually become fully Dystopian or do you think the life could keep up the small Utopia within?

This answer is dependent on countless details, so the answer would have to be "maybe."  It's trivial to show an apparent utopia that crashes into a dystopia.  On the other hand, it's also possible to make utopias that can exist forever, depending on your own individual definition of a utopia.  For example, if your definition of utopia only includes the relative power of things, your utopia can shed energy and other resources into the outer dystopia while remaining utopian, so long as it sheds those things in a way which retains the balances your utopian definition calls for.

One particularly tenuous Utopia is one which is dependent on the possibility that something in the dystopia will eventually cure the demise of the utopia.  As long as the utopia retains enough capabilities to reach out into the dystopia to find that cure when it appears, your utopia retains its status.  Of course, whether this qualifies as a utopia depends *entirely* on you, as there is no defined "best world" that everyone agrees upon.

> If the intelligent life overrun the current government etc, would it have enough technology to keep the world from becoming a dystopia?

Unknown.  One of the great things about our world is we don't know whether what we create will be a dystopia or a utopia.  We have to try it and see.  Also, you get to define what a dystopia is, so you can make it as easy or as hard to become a dystopia as you please.

Answer (score 1):

**An Utopia that "lost its way" and turning into a Dystopia? Absolutely.** There are already enough real-world examples of that happening. And more often than not the "failure" of the Utopia was because of human errors/shortcomings.

**An Utopia which exists side-along a Dystopia? Equally possible.** While "Utopia" is (roughly) defined as the "best possible place to live in for the people of a whole society" it omits the definition of "society" and doesn't cover those who *don't* live in said society.

For the latter version, consider the dichotomy between the Eloi and Morloks in H.G. Well's "Time Machine", picked up in Stephen Baxter's "The Time Ships" where the narrator elaborated a bit on how these two human subspecies began to drift away from their common ancestors.